# ng-repeat not updating DOM when element is inserted dynamically

Tags: json, forms, angularjs, json-framework

I am using [jsonForm](https://github.com/joshfire/jsonform) to generate a form from 3 different json schemas. When on form is submitted, another form is requested and so on... Data on all 3 form creates ONE json object which is sent back and stored after the last form is filled in.

Forms work as expected, the issue is when updating the list **using ng-repeat**

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="names in newName">{{names}}</li>
<ul>
```

**Default names array:**

```
$scope.newName= ["test1","test2"];
```

**initial object**

```
var set1 = {
     "setName": "",
     "setAttributes": [],
    "setQuestions": []

};
```

**Angular:**

```
        $scope.createNewSet = function () {
            $http.get('/json/schema1.json').success(function(data) {
                $('#form1').jsonForm({ // DISPLAY FIRST FORM
                 schema: data,
                 "form": [
                   "*",
                   {
                     "type": "submit",
                     "title": "Proceed to step 2"
                   }
                 ],
                 onSubmit: function (errors, values) { 
                    var sName = values.setName;
                    set1.setName = sName;
                    $http.get('/json/schema2.json').success(function(data) {
                        $('#form2').jsonForm({ //DISPLAY SECOND FORM
                        schema: data,
                        "form": [
                          "*",
                          {
                            "type": "submit",
                            "title": "Proceed to step 3"
                          }
                        ], 
                        onSubmit: function (errors, values) { // DISPLAY THIRD FORM
                            set1.setAttributes = values.attributes;
                            $http.get('/json/schema3.json').success(function(data) {
                            $('#form3').jsonForm({
                               schema: data,
                               "form": [
                                  "*",
                                 {
                                  "type": "submit",
                                  "title": "Proceed to step 4"
                                  }
                                ],
                                onSubmit: function (errors, values) { // SAVE COMPLETE SET
                                  set1.setQuestions = values.questions;
                                  $scope.newName.push(set1.setName);  //UPDATE li
                                  $scope.newName.push('blah')
                                    console.log($scope.newName);
                                },
                              });
                            });
                          },
```

Browser console shows updated newName array `["test1","test2","Simo","blah"]` with `Simo` and `Blah` but HTML doesnt show them. Could there be something preventing angular from updating the DOM?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reapplying the scope:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.newName.push(set1.setName);  //UPDATE li
    $scope.newName.push('blah')
});
```

Comment: QUESTION: do you perhaps know why it worked without `$scope.$apply` on the first and second level? Cause I tested it there it worked without any issues?